# Drupal JSON API on iPhone

Tags: iphone, json, drupal

I am working with an app that is querying a JSON API on a server running Drupal. I used [this tutorial](http://veryniceindustries.com/content/using-drupal-services-iphone-app-api-key) and have changed the code a bit to work with my program, but every request just sends me to the not authorized page that the server generates. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the drupal ios sdk? https://github.com/organizations/workhabitinc

Comment: That only has support for PLIST Server as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah, thats a simple response format to install, http://drupal.org/project/rest_server_plist. I actually implemented a version with JSON kit thats very simple, but why would you want to use JSON over PLIST when Drupal can support both as an endpoint response format? Are you really going to build a JSON request string for every peice of content you have when PLIST can take an NSArray or NSDictionary and pass it to Drupal just like a node object? Save some cycles, use the Drupal iOS SDK, theres no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't set the permissions in the Drupal service.

First go to permissions, and set the desired ones for the modules you're using (I guess you're using the default ones that are included within the services module).

Next, go to Site Building->Services, and authentication. Check if you have any authentication module set, and if so, add the methods that you're using to that key.

At our company we've made several apps which uses Drupal (but using XMLRPC instead of JSON). So feel free to ask everytime you need :)